# Current and magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

When the current in 2 parallel wires flows in same direction they attract each other.Shouldn't the electrons travelling in opposite direction should also repel ?

Comment: If they both travel opposite to the current, they're traveling in the same sense.

Comment: Is your question about why electrons flow opposite the current or why the electrons don't repel each other?  Or both?  It's a bit ambiguous.  To me it seems you are just stating the electrons flowing opposite the current as a fact and then building your question of why the electrons don't repel each other off of that.

Comment: My question is that why the electrons don't repel each other

Answer (score 1):

The electrons that flow to form the current (in the opposite direction) would repel each other if they were the only charged particles in the wire.  However, the wires are made up of atoms, so there are equal amounts of positive charge (protons) and negative charge (electrons) in the wire and thus any electrostatic repulsion between the electrons in the wires is cancelled out by the presence of equal amounts of positive charge in each wire.

Answer (score 0):

> But it said that electrons flow in the direction opposite to current.

That only means that when you say that the *technical direction* of the current is in one direction (say to the right), the *physical direction* of the current is into the other direction (say to the right).

The difference is just that *technical* current assumes positive moving charges, whereas *physical* current “knows” that it is negative electrons (usually).